# C Program freezes after printing to screen

Tags: c

My C program just freezes right after the "zeroed" string printed to the terminal. I can't find out why...

```
            int formattedMsgLen = strlen(msg)+strlen(from)-strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL) + 1;
            printf("formattedMsgLen = %d\n",formattedMsgLen);
            char * formattedMsg = (char*)malloc(formattedMsgLen) ;
            if (NULL == formattedMsg) {
                perror("malloc:");
                sem_post(&writeSem);
                NAMES_MUTEX_UNLOCK;
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("cont. building msg\n");
            //memset(formattedMsg, 0, formattedMsgLen);
            printf("zeroed\n");
            memcpy(formattedMsg, MSG_PRFX_ALL, strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL));
            printf("msg to all: %s",formattedMsg);
```

EDIT:

```
#define MSG_PRFX_ALL ("All")
```

Comment: Are you sure that` MSG_PREFIX_ALL` fits `formattedMsg`?

Comment: You may want a newline after that printf because your buffer may not be flushing.  Are you sure it's freezing?

Comment: I'm sure it's not filling it since I'm sure  MSG_PREFIX_ALL is smaller. Should they be in the same size?

Comment: Can you show us how MSG_PRFX_ALL is declared?

Comment: you will have to make a demo that exhibits this behavior, it is just guessing now.

Comment: added the macro definition

Comment: `memcpy(formattedMsg, MSG_PRFX_ALL, 1+strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL));`

Comment: 1+strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL) not helped, same behavior.

Comment: Are you sure `strlen(msg) + strlen(from)` > `strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL)`?
i.e., are both of them not null strings?

Comment: What do you mean by freezing? What comes after that last `printf`?

Comment: `formattedMsg` only contains "All", but is allocated for some other size. Is that what you want?

Comment: Is this the whole program - any chance that you have stomped memory before this point and it only crashes there because of randomness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a newline character in your last printf statement.

```
    printf("msg to all: %s\n",formattedMsg);
```

This will clear the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL)=3` and `memcpy` just copied only 3 letters without `\0`
add before printf
`formattedMsg[strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL)]='\0'`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line after the last `printf`:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
memcpy(formattedMsg, MSG_PRFX_ALL, strlen(MSG_PRFX_ALL));
```

with

```
strcpy(formattedMsg, MSG_PRFX_ALL);
```